# AddInMemoryClients results in Unknown client or not enabled

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, angular8

I'm trying to get Identity server 4 to work in an ASP Net Core 3 application with an Angular 8 SPA using `"oidc-client": "1.10.1"`.

If I add the following to my appsettings.json

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "acertificate.pfx",
      "Password": "notmyrealpassword..orisit?"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "dev-client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
      }
    }
  }
```

Using this client:

```
 {
      authority: 'https://localhost:5001/',
      client_id: 'dev-client',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
      post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      response_type: 'id_token token',
      scope: 'openid profile API',
      filterProtocolClaims: true,
      loadUserInfo: true
  }
```

I get: `Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:4200/auth-callback`

adding.

```
"dev-client": {
  "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
  "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback" ]
}
```

does nothing. If I add the Client config copied (almost) from the documentation

```
"Clients": [
  {
    "Enabled": true,
    "ClientId": "dev-client",
    "ClientName": "Local Development",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ],
    "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "API" ],
    "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback" ],
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RequireClientSecret": false
  }
]
```

I get: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Type '' is not supported.'` at startup

If I try to configure the client in code, and only keep the "Key" section in appsettings

```
services
.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Cors.CorsPolicyName = _CorsPolicyName;
})
.AddInMemoryClients(new IdentityServer4.Models.Client[] {
new IdentityServer4.Models.Client
{
    ClientId = "dev-client",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    ClientUri = "http://localhost:4200",

    AllowedGrantTypes = { IdentityModel.OidcConstants.GrantTypes.Implicit },
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:4200" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "API"
    }
}
})
```

I get: `Unknown client or not enabled: dev-client`.

Someone help me keep my sanity and point out my, most likely obvious, error.

Comment: The documentation for .net core 3 still very loose... I am having similar issues

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @Tany3450 No. I am now using another security provider and not Identity Server, and my life is much better for it.

Comment: Honestly, there is way too much "magic" going on in the asp net core identity server integration for me to comfortably use that in production. One tiny mistake and the whole thing blows up and you can't really get help anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity overrides the documented method for IdentityServer Clients configuration, expecting a [dictionary of well-known values](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e0b264f1c0e03a8c51a3c58e646fc0db7d3353bc/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Configuration/ConfigureClients.cs#L37-L64). You can bypass this by creating a section that is **not** named `Clients` and reading from that section explicitly. Additionally, `AddApiAuthorization` exposes the Clients collection on the ApiAuthorizationOptions, which can be used to add other clients:

```
.AddApiAuthorization<...>(options =>
            {
                options.Clients.AddRange(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:OtherClients").Get<Client[]>());
            });
```

Comment: TIL. I spent *days* stuck on this. Thank you!

Comment: @MattG same... google doesnt show this search result for querry "identity server 4 'Type '' is not supported.'", but rather some other posts without solution. time to answer them i guess.